# In MySQL view, is it faster to start with union or end with it?

Tags: mysql, performance, view

My database has multiple tables with some matching columns but different names and order.

For example

```
Table1:   FullName Grade Foo
Table2:   Bar Rank WholeName
```

What will be faster:

1) 1 view, repeating the same query for each table

```
CREATE View Test AS
  SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(FullName, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) AS "First Name",
         If (Grade<50, "Bad", "Good") AS "Type"
    FROM table1
  UNION
  SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(WholeName, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) AS "First Name",
         If (Rank<50, "Bad", "Good") AS "Type"
    FROM table2
```

Or

2) 2 views, one for pure merging and a second for manipulations

```
CREATE View Test1 AS
SELECT FullName AS "First Name", Grade AS "Type"
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT WholeName AS "First Name", Rank AS "Type"
FROM table2

CREATE View Test2 AS
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`First Name`, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) AS "First Name",
If (Type<50, "Bad", "Good") AS "Type"
FROM Test1
```

Obviously 1) is more complicated because you have to repeat each and every manipulation. If you had 10 tables, it would have meant repeating the same manipulation 10 times. If you had 10 manipulations, it would have meant writing 100 manipulations instead of just 10. But if it's faster, I'll take it.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48d531/1 suggests roughly the same timing, although in some runs it favors 2).

Please keep in mind there's a lot of data involved and the actual SQL is very complicated and involves LEFT JOINs.

Comment: No views > 1 view > 2 views. Every level of views will limit MySQLs options to optimize the query (e.g. use indexes or join or filter before evaluating every row). You are trying to fix your database model by applying views, this is going to become messy/slow. Ideas: a) store names directly in 2 fields b) store all names in a "user" table and use ids in the 2 tables (removing the `union`) c) do display stuff ("good"/"bad") in your frontend or the outmost query. Now you have 0 views. Fixes/considerations like that are even more relevant if the actual sql is more complicated.

Comment: You're right about fixing the model, but the tables come from different sources with different column names. It sounds reasonable to me to than 1 view is faster than 2, so how come sqlfiddle shows what I wrote? Not sure what a) and b) mean, maybe use sqlfiddle to demonstrate? Not sure why c) will be faster, SQL is done in the server, so I see no benefit to use another server procedure or even worse, client side.

Comment: The execution time on a table with 20 rows will give you no valueable information other than how random hickups influence execution time. A view (in mysql) cannot be faster than a non-view, it just shortens sql code: the code of the view will literally be put in wherever you use the view. What I meant was: you can of course use views to fix your model (e.g. split names on the fly instead of "first name", "last name" in 2 columns in the first place), but as you already saw, it makes things actually more complicated. The first step in every optimization is clean data and a clean data model.

Answer (score 0):

A `VIEW` is syntactic sugar -- try the equivalent `SELECT`.

The "sugar" argument says that Q2 is something like this after resolving the `VIEWs`:

```
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`First Name`,
               ' ', 1), ' ', -1) AS "First Name",
           If (Type<50, "Bad", "Good") AS "Type"
    FROM ( SELECT .. UNION SELECT .. )
```

`FROM ( ... )` is called a "derived" table.  It usually turns into a temp table from which the rest of the select is performed.  This is an extra, moderately heavyweight, step that is avoided in Q1.

In reality, you probably won't notice the difference in performance.

[From the 5.7.6 ChangeLog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-6.html#mysqld-5-7-6-optimizer):

> To handle a derived table (subquery in the FROM clause) or view reference, the optimizer can materialize the derived table or view reference to an internal temporary table or merge it into the outer query block. Previously, derived tables were always materialized, whereas equivalent view references were sometimes materialized and sometimes merged. This inconsistent treatment of equivalent queries could lead to performance problems: Unnecessary derived table materialization takes time and prevents the optimizer from pushing down conditions to derived tables.

That implies that the Answer to your Question depends on what version of MySQL you are using.

[`UNION` optimization in 5.7.3:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-3.html#mysqld-5-7-3-optimizer)

> The server no longer uses a temporary table for UNION statements that meet certain qualifications. Instead, it retains from temporary table creation only the data structures necessary to perform result column typecasting. The table is not fully instantiated and no rows are written to or read from it; rows are sent directly to the client. The result is reduced memory and disk requirements, and smaller delay before the first row is sent to the client because the server need not wait until the last query block is executed. EXPLAIN and optimizer trace output will change: The UNION RESULT query block will not be present because that block is the part that reads from the temporary table. ...
>   [Bug #50674](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=50674)

Comment: 5.6.39, but keep in mind until [version 5.7.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-7.html#mysqld-5-7-7-feature) Views didn't support subqueries in the FROM clause, which is why I didn't include this option in the question. Does your answer still apply without it?

Comment: @LWC - Thanks for pointing that out.  I rephrased my Answer to avoid that 'error'.

Comment: Thanks! But I've added a link to your quote and saw the very next line is _The optimizer now handles derived tables in consistent fashion; that is, the same as view references._ Does it not mean the answer to my question does not depend on the MySQL version (at least in the context you meant)?

Comment: @LWC - `UNION` adds an extra wrinkle.  Can you provide `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...; SHOW WARNINGS;` so we can discuss (I hope) the effect of the lack of, or existence of, the 5.7.7 "improvement".

Comment: @LWC -  Also, I don't trust timings that are only a few milliseconds -- More data could lead to different query plan; outside processes could impact the time; etc.

Comment: @LWC - I added the `UNION` reference.

Comment: EXPLAIN EXTENDED to which of the options? If I do it on 1) I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mvrq.png

Comment: That's part of the `EXPLAIN`, and it does not include the `SHOW WARNINGS;`.  And #2 could be interesting.

Comment: [Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya2o2.png) (1 view) VS [Test2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClKXF.png) (running a view on a view)